# ASP.NET MVC (WEB API) with angular JS passing strong type parameters

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

So I have a controller takes strong typed CarModel object for post request.
In angular js how do I serialize it and pass with post request so the controller will understand it. 
Can someone show a sample code or point to a right direction.

I have only seem people posting on how to pass data for angular js to read it, did not find anything talks about how to post a strong typed object.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("someUrl")]
public IHttpResult PostObject([FromBody]Type name){
    return Ok();
}
```

And from angular

```
$http.post("someUrl", myObject);
```

The javascript object is serialized by angular. The property names just have to match.

Comment: Got you Thank you very much. I am going to try it out tonight when I get home.

Comment: I have added ModelState.IsValid for validation. However, when "myObject" is null, it passed "Modelstate.IsValid" do you know why ?

Comment: @JakeZheng I have no idea what you're using as a validator. But, your object is not invalid. Please open a new thread with a new question.